# How to Factor this polynomial as a product of irreducible polynomial over complex

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I want to factor this polynomial as a product of irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$
$f(x)=X^n - 1 \in \mathbb{R}[X]$

But I’m not sure how to do it. I know that $x^2 -1 is (x-1)(x+1)$ and that the only irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$ are of degree 1

Answer (score 1):

The roots of $x^n -1$ in $\mathbb{C}$ are the [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), which are of the form $$\displaystyle \exp\left({2\pi i \cdot \frac{k}{n}}\right)$$ for $0 \leq k < n$. Once you know the roots it is straightforward to factor. For instance, we have that $p(x) = x^3 - 1 = (x - 1)(x - e^{2\pi i/3})(x - e^{4 \pi i/3})$.

Comment: So $x^4-1 = (x-1)(x-e^{2\pi i/3})(x-e^{4\pi i/3})(x-e^{6\pi i/3})$ ? 

Comment: @user32091 Almost. In that case it should be $4$ in the denominators of the exponents rather than $3$.

Comment: oh your right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The roots are the $n$-th roots of unity in $\mathbf C$: setting $\;\omega=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2i\pi}{n}}$, they are
$$\omega^k=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2ik\pi}{n}},\qquad k=0,1,\dots n-1.$$